# Prestashop 1.7.x - How do I add product's carriers in product list?

Tags: php, prestashop

Today I'm adding visual stickers to my products in order to show the user which carriers will be available, so they won't have a cart with 10 products delivered and 1 to pickup in store.
They'll immediately know what they can do.

No problem on single product page, adding this in ProductController.php is enough :

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'pictures' => $pictures,
            'textFields' => $text_fields,
            'carriers' => $this->product->getCarriers(),
            ));
```

The point comes to product-list page ... I can't seem to find out what I can do to link the carriers to each product of the category.

By looking at ProductListingFrontController.php, I noticed i could get all category products in $variables here :

```
protected function doProductSearch($template, $params = array(), $locale = null)
{
    if ($this->ajax) {
        ob_end_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->ajaxRender(json_encode($this->getAjaxProductSearchVariables()));

        return;
    } else {
        $variables = $this->getProductSearchVariables();
```

Does anybody have already done something like this in Prestashop 1.7.x ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to build a very [simple module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/introduction/) and take advantage of native Prestashop hooks **displayProductListReviews** and **displayProductAdditionalInfo** to return your desired content.

You can easily access all product properties inside the hook *$params* to get the available carriers.